# Issue creating a new project with ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to create a new project in Windows 10 with Ionic with all of its dependencies and modules completely installed.

When i create an app using:

```
ionic start my-app
```

It throws out the following error:

```
> npm install
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

        npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
        npm ERR! code 1
        npm ERR! Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE submodule update -q --init --recursive
        npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: basename: command not found
        npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 7: sed: command not found
        npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 19: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
        npm ERR!

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\Despair\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-27T13_56_55_297Z-debug.log
```

I can't really figure out what's going on. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

```
Here is the commands i ran for info and results I got:

    >ionic info

    global packages:

        @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
        Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

    local packages:

        @ionic/app-scripts              : not installed
        @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
        Ionic Framework                 : not installed

    System:

        Node       : v8.1.2
        OS         : Windows 10
        Xcode      : not installed
        ios-deploy : not installed
        ios-sim    : not installed
        npm        : 5.0.3

npm -v: 

5.0.3
```

Comment: share result of these two commands `ionic info` and `npm -v`

Comment: @mumair I have updated my question with info you asked.

Comment: this is very strange behavior. Can you download and run `npm install` in seed project from here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-angular-cordova-seed so it will confirm either problem is in ionic-cli project generation or in npm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```